# How to make a button clickable in rows in the table with same functionality but for different row (Not add/delete/edit)

Tags: javascript, svelte

For example the open button if I press it should turn to red, but all the buttons in other rows also turn to red because are on the same component.

Script

```
let user = { loggedIn: false };
function toggle(item) {
  user.loggedIn = !user.loggedIn;
}
{#if !user.loggedIn}
  <button id={item.id} class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" on:click={toggle(item)}>
    Open
  </button>
  {/if}  {#if user.loggedIn}
    <button   id={item.id} class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" on:click={toggle(item)}>
      Close
    </button>
  {/if}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you being going as far down as picking the item id, your function is taking only item as a parameter, and below if i understand correclty each item has an `id`

Comment: The click handler needs to be a function, this calls the function directly which returns nothing. Use something like `on:click={() => toggle(item)}`

Answer (score 1):

The ID doesn't really come into play with Svelte styling (unless you want it to).  I think that, at the moment, your problems are with your click handler syntax (as H.B. stated) and likely how you are passing data into your Button component.  I'm also not entirely sure what is going on with `item`, since it isn't really defined anywhere (maybe that's somewhere else in your code?). Taking your example, I trimmed out some of the fat to make it easier to read on SO.  Hopefully I understood what you're trying to do correctly.  Let me know if not, and I'll update.  [REPL Link](https://svelte.dev/repl/831340b3a0cd48218155595f727e8a33?version=3.47.0)(updated: 08.04.2022)

**UPDATE (08.04.2022) **

You can use event dispatching and/or data binding.  You likely will not need both, unless your use case is much more complicated than this post indicates.

[Event Dispatcher](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-events):
To bubble the event back up to the parent, you import createEventDispatcher, then use it to create a dispatcher.  When you dispatch an event (used here in the toggle event), you can create whatever name you want and pass any data you want.  You, then, listen for that in the parent and assign a function to the event (here, `on:eventNameToListenFor={eventFromApp}`).

[Data Binding](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings):
If that feels too heavy-handed and you only need to get the changed data back to App, you can just bind it when you assign it to button: `<Btn bind:user={user} />`

`Button.svelte` (Note the on:click handler and the export let for the user variable).

```html
<script>
    import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
    export let user = { loggedIn: false};
    function toggle() { 
        user.loggedIn = !user.loggedIn; 
        dispatch("eventNameToListenFor", user);
    }
</script>

{#if !user.loggedIn}
  <button class="bg-green-500" on:click={()=>toggle()}>
    Open
  </button>
{:else}
    <button class="bg-red-500" on:click={()=>toggle()}>
        Close
</button>
{/if}
```

`App.svelte` (or whatever is using the Button)

```html
<script>
    import Btn from './Button.svelte'
    let users = [{id: 1, loggedIn: false}, {id: 2, loggedIn: false}, {id: 3, loggedIn: true}];
    const eventFromApp = (event) => {console.log(event.detail)}
</script>
{#each users as user}
    <Btn bind:user={user} on:eventNameToListenFor={eventFromApp}/>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked this way. Regarding this again, if I want to console log something into app.svelte for example the id , how should I define it in the toggle method in button.svelte

Comment: My apologies for missing the reply.  I've updated my answer to include both event dispatchers and data binding.  The REPL link has also been updated with these changes.